# How to remove key and print only data in named tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, psutil

I am getting named tuple as output but I want to use only fields and not key, I did few days back through some trial and error but lost that piece of code.

```
import psutil

cpuTimes = psutil.cpu_times(percpu=flag)
print(cpuTimes)
```

Output:

```
scputimes(user=49296.07, nice=223.37, system=7839.13, idle=217461.5, iowait=209.82, irq=0.0, softirq=91.75, steal=0.0, guest=0.0, guest_nice=0.0)
```

In above output I am getting `scputimes` but I need to remove that, expected output:

```
(user=49296.07, nice=223.37, system=7839.13, idle=217461.5, iowait=209.82, irq=0.0, softirq=91.75, steal=0.0, guest=0.0, guest_nice=0.0)
```

How can I do that without individually printing each value?

Details:

```
Python 3.7
Ubuntu 16
```

Comment: But why you even need that?

Comment: i do not see a difference in your outputs

Comment: @JulianSilvestri the name `scputimes` is not there, that is what they want to achieve

Comment: Use `print(tuple(cpuTimes))`.

Comment: @Puneet actually I had to store lot of variables in json format in text file, many of these object have same key scputimes so I wanted to remove it and store only the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know why you need this, but answering for understanding
Use `str.replace`.

```
>>> str(psutil.cpu_times(percpu=flag)).replace('scputimes(', '').replace(')','')
```